# Sending copies of emails (statuses) prestashop 1.7.2

Tags: email, copy, prestashop

Please how to set copy email status (order done, payment,..) to the administrator?

Comment: Welcome Monika, What did you try so far to achieve that ? Stackoverflow is sadly not a support forum, it's a developper comunity.

Answer (score 0):

Override function `send()` from class `Mail`.

Set `$bcc` parameter and call the parent function:

```
 public static function send(
        $idLang,
        $template,
        $subject,
        $templateVars,
        $to,
        $toName = null,
        $from = null,
        $fromName = null,
        $fileAttachment = null,
        $mode_smtp = null,
        $templatePath = _PS_MAIL_DIR_,
        $die = false,
        $idShop = null,
        $bcc = null,
        $replyTo = null,
        $replyToName = null
    ) {

    $bcc = 'your@mail.com';
    parent:: send($idLang, $template, $subject, $templateVars, $to, $toName, $from, $fromName, $fileAttachment, $mode_smtp, $templatePath, $die, $idShop, $bcc, $replyTo, $replyToName);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but dont work. :-(

Im edit in classes/mail.php

Comment: Could you please let me know exactly what have you done?